# Drawing a Bézier curve

Tags: java, bezier

For a project I'm trying to draw Bézier curves. Now, I created my own `BezierCurve` class that calculates points via [forward differencing](http://www.niksula.hut.fi/~hkankaan/Homepages/bezierfast.html). I'm currently drawing the curve by drawing a `Line2D.Double` between each two points. This is my current output;

[image]
The upper curve (1) is the one I drew with my `BezierCurve` class. The lower curve (2) is the same Bézier curve shifted downwards and drawn by a `GeneralPath` object (using the `curveTo` method).

Now, I can't help but notice that (2) looks alot smoother than (1) Of course I could use `GeneralPath` (or `CubicCurve2D.Double`) myself, but as this is for a project that's not an option.

Now, my question is, is there anything I can do to make the curve look smoother? I tried simply increasing the number of points and using fillRect() but they show no improvement.

Comment: Make the points fare from each in some factor (like 10)

Comment: Consider doing your own [anti-aliazing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing), something that would require a decent understanding of anti-aliazing algorithms and graphics creation.

Comment: @ControlAltDel: I beg to differ. Given his constraints, which are out of his control, the solution is far from trivial.

Comment: As already mentioned, `anti-alias`. If drawing with Swing/Graphics2D, you can enable anti-aliasing by setting a rendering hint through the Graphics2D object.

Comment: @copeg: I think that he would have to roll his own, since Swing anti-aliasing won't work with multiple lines.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, excellent point. Worth a shot.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks. Could you put your comment as an answer? As it is the answer to the question.

Comment: To answer it, I'd have to flesh it out, more so than just posting a link. I'd also have to spell anti-aliasing (**not** anti-aliazing) correctly, two things that I don't have time or ability to do. Consider trying to solve your problem with code, and if successful, then showing your code solution and images as your own answer to your question. This way you can share the fruits of your discovery with others.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Fair enough. I probably won't try it for this project as it's far beyond the scope of it, but it seems like a nice learning experience to do once I have vacation. Will definitely be continued.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to set antialiasing on :

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```